# IIS not serving website pages on remote client

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, iis-7

I am new to IIS and asp and i am having a problem. I am creating a asp.net website in physical folder `wwwroot\SharePage` and virtual directory `SharePage` When i visit the site on local host or using my ip address or through `dyndns`  proxy on my own computer , the page is served fine, But when any one else from any other computer access my website it takes a long time in loading and finally his browser throws an error (may be page not found error,not sure, see for yourself). I have even changed Authentication mode to none and tried with firewalls closed , still page is not served.

You can have a look here

http://thesharepage.dyndns.org/SharePage

(hosted on my home computer so can be unavailable at times when i have switched off my computer)

or try with my ip address

**updated**
http://117.205.103.192/SharePage/

(can change ,i have a dynamic ip address)

Info:
IIS version 7.5
OS : Windows 7
.Net 4 (even in IIS)

please help quick, have to launch it on New Year

Comment: What about some basic troubleshooting like inspecting log files, verifying firewall and routing configuration in your network infrastructure? There are no oracles here…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 80 isn't open to the outside world (I can't telnet to it).  Sounds like IIS is working but your router needs some configuring to forward that port to the server.

Comment: ya found in firewall port 80  and have allowed inbound HTTP traffic to it.. can you gys please check it now.. is it acessible now...

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro: I can now access it.

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro: Yes, with the snowflake background and other styling in tact.  It seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so it is an IIS issue, possible related to firewall. You may need to enable 80 port in your firewall. You may also need to enable port forwarding in your router, even http://thesharepage.dyndns.org/ is not accessible from here.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have not allowed outsiders to access your webserver from outside. This is the default setting in the firewall. Change the setting in your firewall and things will be alright.